# Exception prevents webdriver from responding properly

Tags: python, selenium

Getting some very strange behaviour in the following example code segment:

```
from selenium import webdriver

try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./bin/geckodriver.exe')
    variable = input("Enter something or Ctrl+C: ")
    driver.get(variable)
except:
    pass
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

- If I enter a valid URL, the webdriver fetches the page & then the browser instance is closed.
- If I enter an invalid URL, a `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException` is thrown, but the code progresses & the browser is still closed
- If I press `Ctrl + C` to send the `SIGINT` during the `input` statement:

  - Exception hits `pass` in main method & proceeds to finally

    - Calling just `driver.quit()` returns `None` and Firefox instance is left open
    - Calling `driver.close()` results in `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: ... Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'` and the program terminates with Firefox left open

This is the simplest example I could come up with, but I'm getting the same behaviour in some code that I'm writing when `WebDriverWait`'s are interrupted or when seemingly unrelated code throws an Exception; suddenly the `webdriver` instance is unresponsive. This is a problem since it leaves headless Firefox instances open. Is this a known issue when working with Selenium, or am I doing something I shouldn't be?

The Firefox version being used is Quantum v64 & Geckodriver is v0.23.0; both should be up-to-date.

**Edit**: Using `pdb` to step through the code, the driver instance is created & firefox opens, it prompts for the input and I press `Ctrl+C`, `driver.get(variable)` is ***not*** executed, the code moves to `except` and then to `finally`, and I receive a `MaxRetryError` out of nowhere. If I replace the `input(..)` line with: `raise KeyboardInterrupt()`, then the browser closes as expected; I'm not sure why the program has this behaviour in response to `Ctrl+C`.

**Edit (2)**: Reported this as a bug on the [Selenium Github Repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6826). Python version difference was suggested, but I retried under 3.7.2 (most recent) and still exhibiting the same behaviour-- Selenium / Firefox / Python / Geckodriver are all now as up-to-date as they can be & I'm still running into this issue-- Hopefully this gets resolved; seemingly, this is not an issue with the code I've written.

Comment: Why are you sending _Ctrl + C to send the SIGINT_? What is your _usecase_? Are you testing _Selenium APIs_?

Comment: @DebanjanB No sorry, this was the simplest code example which seemed to replicate the exact error I was receiving. Was meant to illustrate that under certain circumstances when an exception is thrown, the webdriver instance later exhibits this behaviour of being unresponsive. However, at points in my current script/application if a user forcibly quits with `Ctrl+C`, even if the code is wrapped in a `finally` which is supposed to close the browser- it remains open. Though this seems to happen with virtually any exception.

Comment: I revised the code slightly to make it more apparent where the exception is being generated. Surely that's strange behaviour though? I create a webdriver instance without problems, the next line throws an exception & it's not directly related to the webdriver object, and yet in the finally statement, the webdriver object can't be closed & throws a urllib3 error.